# Cannot reach SIP server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, voip, nat

I'm developing a VoIP IOS app using SIP protocol. I have my own SIP parser library and I use GCDAsyncUDPSocket to send data to the server.

The problem is that I can't reach the server on double NAT with my app. I do PING and the server responds immediately PONG, but when I send a SIP package, I can't even reach the server.

I try to reach the server with other clients like Zoiper or Media5 and works perfectly. So I think i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to:

- include your private IP:port in the contact and via headers (not a wrong public address)
- add the rport attribute to Via
- make sure that the REGISTER message is well formed (is a valid SIP message)

If still doesn't work, check the server logs. If still doesn't work or you don't have access to the server logs, let me see your REGISTER message.

Comment: Actually I'm totally sure I'm including my private IP and port where I'm sending from and when I check the server log the port has changed for no reason (I guess the modem is doing that). I'm including the rport in Via and I'm testing with a REGISTER message I took from Zoiper. Still doesn't work

Comment: A lot's of routers/modems has something like SIP-alg try to be smart but most of time just creating problems. In this case you should configure your server to always honor the psychical address (from where the sip message was received from on the UDP socket) instead of the address presented in the sip signaling.

Comment: Can I show you one of my REGISTER messages? I still don't know why Zoiper is working and my app doesn't.

Comment: Yes, show me your register message (also let me know what is your server address:port)

Comment: REGISTER sip:00000001-107-exten@proxy1.cloudvoice.mx SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.123.135:52602;rport;branch=z9hG4bKZVjSvIB
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:00000001-107-exten@proxy1.cloudvoice.mx>;tag=rqSzYZYvj
To: <sip:00000001-107-exten@proxy1.cloudvoice.mx>
Call-ID: pOjp7gFHFnr5MqSMAqU
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:00000001-107-exten@192.168.123.135:52602;transport=UDP>
User-Agent: iPhone
Expires: 60
Local-Port: 192.168.123.135:52602
Token-Iphone: 
Content-Length: 0

Address: proxy1.cloudvoice.mx
Port: 5060

Comment: I am sorry, but it is hard to interpret this because if the loss if new lines.Otherwise the message looks ok. You might try to send it from a public IP and if you receive answer in that case, that would mean that this proxy can't handle NAT. Or maybe you have a transport level problem (not reading from UDP), Try a simple UDP ping-pong first to verify if your UDP socket is ok.